# onexit - request an url

Tags: javascript, mobile, nokia-wrt

I've some problem with requesting an URL when finishing (exit) the widget. I try to use it via window.widget.onexit on request then an logout URL which makes some logs in the backend. I tried it by the following ways:

```
window.widget.onexit = function() {

 xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
 xhr.open("GET", "http://new-ken.de/alwaysOn/php/logout.php", false );   
 xhr.send(""); 

}
```

AND

```
window.widget.onexit = function() {

  window.location.href = "http://new-ken.de/alwaysOn/php/logout.php";

}
```

Does somebody have an idea to solve this little problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this code:

```
widget.openURL("http://new-ken.de/alwaysOn/php/logout.php");
```